# Async await in Controller Action: Error: Can not await 'void'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I am using async to controller action which returns jsonresult.
and send notification methods returns void.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SetStatus(string msg)
{
    await SendNotification(msg);
}
```

I am getting error 'Can not await 'void'

Comment: I think you must return a Task<JsonResult>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `SendNotification` has to return `Task`, by `await` keyword definition.

It's kind of `javascript` promise (just to give you an idea), which has to have `done`, `failed` functions, in order to be able track execution flow of async function.

Comment: Technically, `await` only needs an "awaitable"; but `Task<T>` and `Task` are the most commonly-used awaitables.